# The appbarlayout does not show on kit kat devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface

Image of application on kit kat devices.

[image]

The AppbarLayout does not show anything on kit kat devices and yet it shows on lollipop and above.
What could cause this kind of issue . 
Here's the activity layout

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <!-- The  main toolbar -->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        >

        <!--Spinner for fro language-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/main_fro_lang_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"/>

        <!-- Swap Icons-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/main_swap_lang_imageview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|center_vertical"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_swap_horiz_white_48dp"
            android:onClick="onClickSwapSpinnerLangs"
            />

        <!--Spinner for fro language-->
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:id="@+id/main_to_lang_spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"/>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: Please show the manifest of the activity including it and the xml of the activity where the include statement is shown for this toolbar to be used, and then the setOnActionbar that is wiring it up. Lastly, the folder structure where your layout lives and any Graphics being used in this toolbar as kitkat is a picky OS and a giant pain in the butt at times. If you can avoid it I do haha

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to enclose you layout into CoordinatorLayout?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    > 
 -- AppBarLayout here --
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: it is enclosed in a coordinatorlayout